# Can't use my own font CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to add a different font to my website and I'm having some issues. I have checked a few stackoverflow questions, but none of them seems to fix my problem:/ 
I'm using this code here:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Hand";
    src: url(ownhand.ttf) format("truetype");
    }
```

And it works perfectly in local, but for some reason when I upload the file to my domain it turns out to appear as times new roman again. Any ideas on why is that happening? Could it be a protection problem??

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried navigating to `ownhand.ttf` in a web browser hosted on the server to see if the web server is serving the file correctly?

Comment: what browsers, operating system are you testing in?  It could be a user permission problem, it could also be a file permission problem.  It could be because you're not using the right file format for the browser you're looking at.

Comment: Look at your chrome developer tools and look at the request for your ownhand.ttf file. Any errors there?

Comment: I'm so sorry but I'm really new at programming, so I get quite lost with all the computers terminology.  
@ntgCleaner I am using google chrome alwas (same in localhost).

Comment: @JuanMendes Where do you say that I have to go?? Do I have to download Chrome DevTools (I have just googled it)

Comment: right click on your browser and select "inspect Element"

Comment: Using Chrome, press `F12`, or `ctrl+shift+i`, the dev tools app will come up

Answer (score 0):

Here what i am using and it works for me.  you would need serprate file for each broswer .  I dont have font for IE in following code.  THis works for chrome and firefox.

```
@font-face {
        font-family: "OpenSans Light";
        src: url('/csspath/OpenSans-Light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), 
             url('/csspath/OpenSans-Light-webfont.eot') format('eot');
}
```

Comment: I think the code is fine, it works when opening the file on local. The problem is only though the web, so it makes me think that there's somehting else.

Comment: On chorme->inpsect element and goto network tab to see if css files are loaded .   Do you see your css file there?

Comment: Yes, I see my css file there. And besides, there is much more information on this file that actually appears. The proble is just that d*ammed font-family... :(

Comment: Do you also see your ownhand.ttf file there?

Comment: When I go to styles/ownhand.ttf the file is downloaded

Comment: you are only using chrome right?  because ttf wont work for anyother browser